# Can't search my database for relevant data || Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql

So i'm trying to search my database using to text input fields, both have name and id attributes, one has product for both of these, the other has brand for both. The problem comes with the PHP, it connects to the database just fine, and it claims to accept the sql statement, but once it gets to a certain line (which will have a comment above it in the code below), it gives me the error "Trying to get property of non-object", and i believe that this line is required for a database search to work in the first place. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!--This is the form used to submit the query-->

<form action="searchDB.php" method="GET" id="searchForm">
            <input type="text" name="product" id="product" placeholder="Product...">
            <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand" placeholder="Brand...">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
```

PHP/MySQL:

```
$product = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['product']);
$brand = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['brand']);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbase);

if(empty($_GET['product']||$_GET['brand'])){ //fields contain no value
    die('please input a search!'); // kill the database connection
}

if ($conn->connect_error) {
echo "Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error;
}else{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product = $product AND brand = $brand";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//echo $sql;
}

//THIS IS WHERE IT SAYS THE ERROR OCCURS, "if($result->num_rows>0" 
//specifically
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    //output each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "Product: " . $row["product"]. " Brand: " . $row["brand"]. " 
Age: " . $row["age"]. " Cost: " . $row["cost"]. " Specification: " . 
$row["specification"]. " Image: " . $row["image"]. "<br>";
    }
}else{
    echo "Sorry, we could not find any products relating to your search.";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: you can't use an escape function before connecting (you're putting the wagon before the horse), and your WHERE clause failed if any of those are strings.

Comment: your form is missing the closing tag; unless that was a bad paste

Comment: Then clearly `$result` isn't an object.  So what is it?  If the query failed, it's a boolean.  Did the query fail?  Most likely, especially given the SQL injection vulnerability.  You need to check for that.

Comment: what does `echo $sql;` show?

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile It just shows my sql statment onscreen, to make sure it has gone thorugh.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Bad paste, sorry. So you mean the escape strings should come after the $conn or after if($conn->connect error)?

Comment: @David so how would i test for that?

Comment: @MatthewWallace: Check if the result is `false`.  If so: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @MatthewWallace I had to make sure, that's why I asked. And yes, the escape functions go after the connection was established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, you can't use the escape function before the connection was established.

Your connection logic also needed to be modified, so here's what we end up with, along with a few modifications such as adding the `empty()` to the other GET array.

I also quoted the variables in VALUES since those stand to be strings.

Make sure that both of those values get satisfied, otherwise you may need to change the `AND` to an `OR` operator.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbase);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
echo "Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error;
}

if(empty($_GET['product']) || empty($_GET['brand']) ){
    die('please input a search!');
}else{

$product = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['product']);
$brand = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['brand']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product = '$product' AND brand = '$brand'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if(!$result){

    echo "The query failed: " . mysqli_error($conn);

}

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    //output each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "Product: " . $row["product"]. " Brand: " . $row["brand"]. " 
Age: " . $row["age"]. " Cost: " . $row["cost"]. " Specification: " . 
$row["specification"]. " Image: " . $row["image"]. "<br>";
    }
}else{
    echo "Sorry, we could not find any products relating to your search.";
    }

}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

and as I also stated in comments, if what you posted is your actual code, it's missing the closing `</form>` tag.

Check for errors against the query with `mysqli_error($conn)`.

Note: Use a prepared statement, they're much better to help guard against an SQL injection.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works now! I appreciate your time.